# Staff timetabling software?

Tags: linux, web-apps, time-management

I have a new role which requires me, among other things, to staff some tertiary courses.  The timetable is fixed, so what I have to do is to scatter staff among the various subjects so that each person has the right number of hours (and everybody's availability is different, depending on their other duties), and ensure that every class is staffed, and that nobody has too many hours without a break.

So I'm looking for software which will enable me to fill in such a timetable, and then report on individual staff, subjects, student groups, days of the week etc.  I've been managing so far with spreadsheets, but these are a clumsy tool for this task.

I would want a tool that is either web-based, or runs under Linux (even better, has both Linux and Windows versions).  And is open-source.

I run my own server, so I can install a web-based system for myself if that's the way to go.

There are so many timetabling options available I'm not sure what may be best for me.  I also don't mind using MATLAB, GNU Octave, Python, or any other programming language or system.

Happy to take any recommendations on board!

Comment: Are you looking for gratis software or would you be willing to pay for it? If the latter, how much?

Comment: Rather late for the now, but I would suggest trawling GitHub, SourceForge, etc. Also, there are some similar questions on this site, with the [tag:time-management] tag